# CM database stricture change list after upgrade to Web 8

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8, upgrade, database

I was wondering if there is a list of all changes done on CM database after upgrade to web 8. The changes I am interested are added/removed tables and fields, store procedure updates and etc. I know that internal database workings are in SDL scope and should not be publicly exposed (Core Service API and TOM.NET API should be used for items manipulation), but it would be nice to have that sort of list.

Comment: Don't think it exists (at least I haven't seen it) and as you say SDL won't publish it. Might be easy to figure it out by looking at the upgrade scripts though.

Comment: Yes I thought to go through them, but am a bit lazy so I figured maybe someone already listed it. :)

Comment: If it exists, it's probably not (very) publicly shared...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CM database schema is officially not public and direct connections to the database are not supported by SDL.

Therefore, it is not in SDL's interest to officially publish a list of changes to the schema; it may give a false impression that the schema is public.

But, as Nuno mentioned, the schema is a public secret and you can easily find the changes by looking at the SQL upgrade scripts.

Comment: Yes I agree. I just thought that someone already listed this changes. Thanks for response.